# Generating random values with restricted digits

Tags: php, random

What is the best way to generate a random integer with a restricted set of digits?

I want to generate a 4 digit random number, where each digit is in the range [1..6]. I was thinking generate a number in the range [0..1295], then converting to base 6 and incrementing the digits, but that goes through a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without string conversion, and with only one call to a random number generator, you could do this:

```
function myRandom() {
    $num = mt_rand(0, 1295);
    $result = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $result = $result*10 + $num % 6;
        $num = floor($num / 6);
    }
    return $result + 1111;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate each digit separately like this:

```
$result = '';
for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) { 
    $result .= mt_rand(1, 6);
}
$result = (int) $result;
```

Or if using a string is not preferred, you could do it with math:

```
$result = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $result += mt_rand(1, 6) * 10 ** $i;

    // or for PHP versions < 5.6 (no ** exponentiation operator)
    // $result += mt_rand(1, 6) * pow(10, $i); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//  216_10 = 1000_6
// 1295_10 = 5555_6
base_convert(mt_rand(216,1295),10,6);
```

Comment: Some digits will not be in the range [1..6]. (Sorry, not trying to pick on you.)

Comment: yep.. I see.. I've missed some conditions in the question... your answer seems more accurately.. but not universal (though OP doesn't talk about it) .. I mean we can use any set of characters not only digits.. sry for off-topic )